# How I Can use From Email dynamically while using Twilio Verify create API

Tags: twilio, sendgrid, twilio-api

As per the Twilio Sendgrid documenation, there is no way to Pass the From Email id in payload while sending email, sharing the code below for reference. I just want to know is there any way to possible add From Email id in below code while sending verification link for ``` Email ``channel ```.

```
  public HttpResponseMessage VerifyLink(Payload payload)
        {
            
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            string accountSid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accSid"]; 
            string authToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridAut"];             
            var verifyServiceSid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["verServiceSid"] ;                                                           
            TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);            
            try
            {
                // Create verification
                var verification = VerificationResource.Create(
                    to: payload.email,
                    channel: "email",
                    pathServiceSid: verifyServiceSid,
                    channelConfiguration: new
                    {
                        substitutions = new
                        {
                            username = payload.userName,
                            email = payload.email,
                            callback_url = payload.callback_url
                        }
                    }
                );
                var verificationValue = verification;
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "true");
                telemetry.TrackTrace("Verify Email Link Sent Successfully by Createverificationlink API End");
                return response;
            }}
```

As of now I kept the From Email id in Twilio Verify Service under Twilio Account console but this is not usefull solution where we have more then 20 different email and equalent service we need to create, Twilio provide anything so that we can add the From email in code section while sending the email as like To Email. For us those email needs to verify sendGrid account under sender authentication which again a additional work, normaly we can add any from email while sending email from sendgrid.

I try this code:-

```
  public HttpResponseMessage VerifyLink(Payload payload)
        {
            
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            string accountSid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accSid"]; 
            string authToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridAut"];             
            var verifyServiceSid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["verServiceSid"] ;                                                           
            TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);            
            try
            {
                // Create verification
                var verification = VerificationResource.Create(
                    to: payload.email,
                    channel: "email",
                    pathServiceSid: verifyServiceSid,
                    channelConfiguration: new
                    {
                        substitutions = new
                        {
                            username = payload.userName,
                            email = payload.email,
                            callback_url = payload.callback_url
                        }
                    }
                );
                var verificationValue = verification;
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "true");
                telemetry.TrackTrace("Verify Email Link Sent Successfully by Createverificationlink API End");
                return response;
            }}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there's currently no way to specify it in code. What you can do is create **one Verify service per "From" configuration,** and then use different services based on the sender you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Just quick question around this only, I am getting the input field for From Email id in Verify service but not getting the option for Reply To, do you know how i can handle this because in code this is possbile but after intigrating Twilio Service then struggling.

Comment: There's none.  I'm not sure why this field would be helpful as the recipients of OTP codes are usually not supposed to respond to the email.